# Hide NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Im my app i have an Activity called `MainActivity` it contains a dynamic fragment with id `container` which i switch depending on state usually my app can be in the state `Syncing` or `Regular` now i wan't to add a `NavigationDrawer`to and i want it to be visible in the ActionBar and on the left only if the `MainActivity`is not on the `Syncing`state since that if the Activity  `Synching` i should not be abble to use the drawer to navigate in my app.
Im using the following activity layout

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using 
  match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="pt.ecs.myenergy.MainActivity">

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
<!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. -->
<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="---------.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The question is for a clever/best way to achieve this. I tought of a few but im not sure which one to use:

1. Have two xml layouts for the activity, one with the drawer included other without it and  use setContentView which would cause for the xml to be inflated not sure if this is a good aproach
2. Use the merge tag with two childs one the drawer layout (with the container) other with only the container (for the syncing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest doing none of those options. They both seem over complicate for no good reason for me.

you should lock the drawer closed using: [`drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#setDrawerLockMode(int))

and if you're also using the an `ActionBarDrawerToggle` you disable it's indicator with [`drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(boolean))

Comment: Perfect i knew about the `setDrawerIndicatorEnabled` but missed the `setDrawerLockMode` thanks will try it